# Is BGA-Studio friendly to new programmers?

Tags: board-game-adaptations

I love [Board Game Arena (BGA)](https://en.boardgamearena.com/), imho, it is the best **real time** board games site.

They have a [studio](http://en.studio.boardgamearena.com/) where anyone can build and post new games.  I tried to build a simple bidding-tic-tac-toe, however I got stuck in all kinds of places.

Is BGA studio a friendly site to new programers?  I ask since on first (and second) glance it does not feel very friendly.  **What I must know in order to build a small simple game on BGA-studio?**

Comment: While this is board game related I am not sure that it can be answered on this site as it depends on knowledge that is not board game related at all. I am not sure that a question like this is a good fit for any of the stack exchange sites.

Comment: should I delete this question?

Comment: whilst the above comment is correct, its not really a Boardgames SE question I'm glad you mentioned it as was something I wasn't aware of at all and might look into when I get a chance.

Comment: That is up to you, I was just pointing out that this question is not a good fit and going to have a hard time getting answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site seems pretty clear that it is not for new programmers. The description on the front page of who Studio is for says

"You are a web developer fluent in server side (PHP, SQL) and client side (HTML, Javascript) languages"

Comment: Adding to this, the tools are meant to develop complicated games, and is not a toy tool to make an easy game. in fact, it includes messaging other users and some other not newbie things